# AFNetworking Memory

Tags: afnetworking

Using AFNetworking to download files from a server. Here's the code:

```
self.networkQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];

for(NSDictionary* fileDictionary in self.syncArray) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        if([[fileDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"downloadZipURL"]) {
            NSString* downloadPath = [fileDictionary objectForKey:@"downloadZipURL"];
            downloadPath = [downloadPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadPath]];

            NSString* localDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [FileUtil userDocumentsDirectory], [downloadPath lastPathComponent]];
            NSString* localTempPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.tmp", localDestPath];
            [(NSMutableDictionary*)fileDictionary setObject:localDestPath forKey:@"downloadDestination"];

            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL];
            operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:localDestPath append:NO];
            operation.userInfo = fileDictionary;

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                if (networkQueue.operationCount == 0)
                {
                    if(hasDownloadError || isCancellingSync) {
                        return ;
                    }

                    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processAllFiles) withObject:nil];

                }

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];

            //            [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            //                NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes, %@", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, localDestPath);
            //                float progress = (float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
            //                [(NSMutableDictionary*)operation.userInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %.0f%%", progress*100] forKey:@"downloadStatus"];
            //                [(NSMutableDictionary*)operation.userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress] forKey:@"downloadProgress"];
            //                [syncViewController onPermitUpdated];
            //            }];

            [networkQueue addOperation:operation];
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that once this code is run, memory slowly gets eaten up and never given back. Now, these can be large files, which is why I used the outputStream.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Off the top of my head - I see that you're not using ARC.

`AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL]`

Are you releasing this operation somewhere?

```
 [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                if (networkQueue.operationCount == 0)
                {
                    if(hasDownloadError || isCancellingSync) {
                        return ;
                    }

                    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processAllFiles) withObject:nil];

                }
```

Here, you're using the networkQueue in the completionBlock and the block retains the networkQueue, you then add the operation to the networkQueue, which retains the operation, which leads to neither of them deallocating. Try making a weak variable of the networkQueue and use that in order to break the cycle.

If these don't work - run instruments and make a note of what objects remain in memory and when their reference count is changed.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. Newb at Object C. First, isn't ARC an all or nothing proposition? I can't just use it on networkQueue can I? Doesn't autorelease on the networkQueue handle deallocation? Still doesn't solve my problem of growing memory as the huge files are being downloaded.

Comment: Yes, it's all or nothing and you can't just use it for the networkQueue and yes, autorelease will release the networkQueue, but it won't release the operation itself, you should do that.
Did you take care of that? It's possible that if you don't release the operation, it holds on to some of that data - I'm not sure what the implementation of that is.

Comment: Just looking at the code too much I guess. I missed the operation not being released. I put autorelease on that also. Even after the downloading is done, the memory is still taken.